# How to tell screen use use different bash_profile?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, bashrc, profile

How can I tell to screen to use different bash_profile? Problem is we use a technical user to log in, but I edited a custom PS1.

Normally I login with putty like:
ssh user@host -t "bash --rcfile ~/.profile.custom -i"

But screen use the default setting.
Setting it as parameter after '`shell -"/usr/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.profile.custom -i`" or '`shell -$SHELL --rcfile ~/.profile.custom -i`' in .*screenrc* didn't worked because screen terminated after 2 second without doing anything

-->!!ENV1!!<-- user@host:ENV1:/app1/users/home]$screen

[screen is terminating]